# Extra row appended when adding columns to CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am reading in CSV files, removing the header, and appending two columns of data. Everything is working great, aside from an extra row being added at the end. For example, if I have the following input file:

```
headerA | headerB | headerC
   a    |    b    |    c
   d    |    e    |    f
```

I want the output file to look like:

```
   a    |    b    |    c    |    g    |    h
   d    |    e    |    f    |    g    |    h
```

But it's coming out like:

```
   a    |    b    |    c    |    g    |    h
   d    |    e    |    f    |    g    |    h
   g    |    h
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is the case. If anyone has a solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
for fileName in os.listdir(inPath):
    if fileName.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(inPath + fileName, 'rb') as csvin:
            reader = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter=',')
            i = reader.next()
            with open(outPath + 'wrng_' + fileName, 'wb') as csvout:
                writer = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter=',')                         
                for row in reader:
                    j = fileName.split("_")[1].replace(".csv","")
                    row.append(j[2:-7] + '-' + j[4:-5] + '-' + j[:2] + ' ' + j[7:-2] + ':' + j[9:] + ':00')
                    row.append(i[1].split(" ")[2][:-1])
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Is there an empty line at the end of the CSV file?

Comment: @roganjosh When I use `extend()` it splits it into separate characters, so "1000" would turn into "1,0,0,0". I also still get the extra row added at the end when I use `extend()`.

Comment: @digitaLink Yeah, there is. I tried to add an if statement somewhere that would catch empty rows but wasn't sure how to do that. Would that be the solution?

Comment: The blank line was the issue... added a `if row:` statement under the `for row in reader:`. Thank you both!

Comment: You should consider using `glob.glob('*.csv')` which will shorten your code and help lose some `if`s - https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Summarizing from the comments) It looks like the problem you are having could be caused by an empty row at the end of the file. You can check to see if the row is empty within your for loop.

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
    ...
```